# Rotation in Blender

Tags: shortcut

I just started learning blender yesterday. In my model, there is an octagonal prism I created by changing the amount of vertices in a cylinder. I want it to be sideways, and have the **flat part** facing the ground. By default, it's skewed 22.5 degrees so that the edge is facing the ground. While the rectangle was still standing up, I turned it the appropriate amount of degrees. I then set the y rotation to 90 degrees so the cylinder is on its side. However, instead of lying on one of the faces, it is still on the same edge, but is at a different angle. This is because when I turned it, all of its axises turned with it, so nothing really changed. However, I want it to rotate on the global axises. I looked in the documentation, and it was for blender 2.4 and all the shortcuts are different now. What I am trying to accomplish is probably pretty common, so can anybody who knows what to do please help me with this? Thanks.

[image: The one on the left is how it would show up if I only rotated y by 90 degrees, the right shows how I intend for it to look]

Comment: The current manual page is [docs.blender.org](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/), specifically about rotation - https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/translation_rotation_scale.html. I suggest using it only for shortcuts and certain info, for tutorials use youtube or alike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press R on your keyboard to rotate your object. You can choose a specific rotation, you can presss either X, Y, or Z. On your keyboard. Then simply type any number to change the rotation. In this case, press R and then X on your keyboard to change the sideways rotation.

(The next time you post a question, make sure to research it before you post your question.)

Comment: I did do research, and I read those shortcuts. They didn't mention pressing "r" first. Thanks for answering